# Golang WMI query XP

Tags: go, wmi, ole

I'm using mattn's go-ole package to connect to WMI, I got this working using some examples I found on stack and all is fine until I try to make it work in Win XP. The Microsoft documentation says `thatWbemScripting.SWbemLocator` is only available for Vista so I've been trying the `winmgmts` method that Microsoft shows for use on VBScript but i'm not getting anywhere.

Here is what I have.

This works on Win 7:

```
wmiscriptObj, err := oleutil.CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
```

This doesn't work in either XP or 7:

```
wmiscriptObj, err := oleutil.CreateObject("winmgmts:\\\\.\\root\\cimv2")
```

I get invalid class as an error.

Not sure if this helps explain things but in the past I've used Autoit to query WMI on XP and I can connect with this:

```
$objWMIService = ObjGet("winmgmts:\\" & $ComputerName & "\root\CIMV2")
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the second approach works if you replace `CreateObject` with `GetActiveObject`?

Comment: I've just given this a try and again I get "invalid class string".

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this question and wanted to provide an answer.

To connect to a namespace / winmgmts, you need to execute the Connect - method using the badly documented namespace argument.

Sample code
    package main

```
import (
    "github.com/go-ole/go-ole"
    "github.com/go-ole/go-ole/oleutil"
)

func main() {
    ole.CoInitializeEx(0, ole.COINIT_MULTITHREADED)
    defer ole.CoUninitialize()

    unknown, err := oleutil.CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    defer unknown.Release()

    wmi, err := unknown.QueryInterface(ole.IID_IDispatch)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    defer wmi.Release()

    // Connect to namespace
    // root/PanasonicPC = winmgmts:\\.\root\PanasonicPC
    serviceRaw, err := oleutil.CallMethod(wmi, "ConnectServer", nil, "root/PanasonicPC")
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    service := serviceRaw.ToIDispatch()
    defer serviceRaw.Clear()

    // Interact with service object etc
}
```